# How to separate punctuations in a String in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I am basically parsing data from a file. At some point in my code, I am splitting each line of the file based on the space character --> str.split(" "). What I need is a way to separate out any punctuations that might occur in the string.

When I say puncutation, I mean any of the characters returned by

```
import string
print (string.punctuation)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you save a copy of the original string to avoid 're-inserting' the punctuation back in?

Comment: You could make a regex out of the punctuation in string.punctuation, using capture groups to store every piece of punctuation that you match while splitting the string up on every match. Then you can operate on your list of strings and re-join it by your taken out matches.

Answer (score 3):

I would use regex for this:

```
>>> re.split(r'(\W)', 'This is a sentence. This is another sentence.')
    ['This',
 ' ',
 'is',
 ' ',
 'a',
 ' ',
 'sentence',
 '.',
 '',
 ' ',
 'This',
 ' ',
 'is',
 ' ',
 'another',
 ' ',
 'sentence',
 '.',
 '']
```

You can run through the resulting list, change the words, and then `''.join()` it back into a sentence with the same punctuation in the same places.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to just hang on to the original, wouldn't it? What's your end goal of putting the punctuation back in? If you're just going to rebuild the whole line, why not just keep it in the first place?

```
pattern = '['+''.join(string.punctuation)+']+' # Make a char set in regex syntax

for line in file:
    tokens = line.split(' ')
    for token in tokens:
        parsed = parse_token(re.sub(pattern, token))
        # Now do whatever else you might need to do with token and parsed.
    # Remember, you still have access to the `line` string and `tokens` list!

def parse_token(token):
    pass # Do whatever you need to do with your "clean" token here.
```